# Iterate through multiple columns in a Panda dataframe and find count unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a dataset which looks like below:

[image]

I have imported this dataset to my code using the panda library. My goal is to find unique entries of the programming languages from columns 2, 3, 4. I wish the output to be:

```
    Python 4
    Perl 3
    C++ 3
....
```

Any leads would be helpful

Comment: Outpus should be Series? List?

Comment: Output should be in List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = df.filter(like='Language').stack().value_counts()
```

Comment: First options gives me count values present in each column:

Out[92]:
Name         30
Language1    14
Language2    13
Language3    15
Awardedon     3

Second option gives list of languages , but doesnot provides the count
'Agile',
 'BMC-Remedy',
 'C',
 'C++',
 'Java',
 'Java Script',
 'Manual Testing',
 'Perl',]

Comment: @newuser - some problem with my solution?

Comment: @newuser - If need Series use `s = df.filter(like='Language').stack().value_counts()` only.

Comment: Its Perfectly fine @jezrael. I have marked your comment as the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative way

```
df['lang1'].value_counts() + df['lang2'].value_counts() + df['lang3'].value_counts()
```

or

```
cols = ['lang1', 'lang2', 'lang2']
sum([df[col].value_counts() for col in cols])
```